# Bing Maps Search Box Element ID

Tags: vb.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bing-maps

`enter code here`Currently I have my program set up to take information from my text box to search Bing.com and currently looks for the element ID "q" which is the Bing Search box it then searches for what ever I put in that text box. Recently I decided to redirect it to Bing maps but cannot find the element ID for that search box.

An alternative which I would like it to insert a basic Google Maps API of which I have the code from http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/google_maps_basic.asp

but I don't know how to incorporate this into a small web browser window inside of my application

Answer (score 0):

Full documentation on how to create custom URL's for the Bing Maps consumer can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx